# How to access arguments from another function to validate them in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

I need to validate the arguments of a callback function. I have a function that takes count and a func, count checks if the number of passed arguments to a func were correct. I have tried to make other function inside my function that would connect arguments

```
function checkFunc() {
   func.apply(null, arguments);
     return [...arguments];
 }
```

But I receive func.apply is not a function. SO I made it in another way but it still doesn't work.
Here is the code with example

```
const withParamsCountValidation = (count, func) => {
  function checkFunc(args1, ...args) {
    return func(args1, ...args);
  }
  if (typeof count === 'number' && checkFunc().length !== count.length) {
    new Error`You should pass no more than ${count} parameters`();
  }
  if (
    Array.isArray(count) &&
    count.length === 2 &&
    checkFunc().length >= count[0] &&
    checkFunc().length <= count[1]
  ) {
    true;
  }
  new Error`You should pass at least ${count[0]} and no more than ${count[1]} parameters`();
};

console.log(withParamsCountValidation(3, test(1, 2)));

function test(som, som2, som3) {
  return som + som2 + som3;
}
```

Comment: Why don't separate the function arguments validator from that function and return the `boolean` result that tells whether the arguments are valid or not?

Comment: What do you mean? Separate how?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your problem before. I think it's not possible sending function with its own parameters as a parameter for another function.

Comment: `test(1,2)` is not a function, it evaluates to `NaN` - you cannot call that. You need to write either `withParamsCountValidation(3, test)(1, 2)` or `callWithParamsCountValidation(3, test, 1, 2)` or `applyWithParamsCountValidation(3, test, [1, 2])`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it via closures if someone needs:

```
const withParamsCountValidation = (count, func) => {
  func = function () {
    return function (...args) {
      console.log("args", args, "count", count);
      if (typeof count === "number" && args.length !== count) {
        throw new Error(`You should pass no more than ${count} parameters`);
      }

      if (
        Array.isArray(count) &&
        count.length === 2 &&
        args.length >= count[0] &&
        args.length <= count[1]
      ) {
        return true;
      }
      throw new Error(
        `You should pass at least ${count[0]} and no more than ${count[1]} parameters`
      );
    };
  };
  return func(count);
};
```

Comment: What does `withParamsCountValidation` take a `func` as its second parameter? You're not using that anywhere. Did you mean to actually call that if the validation suceeds?